# Mic input and Speaker output using arduino

Tags: interrupt

I am trying to make a small project. Firstly, I want to record voice using a small microphone(electret) for the time button is pressed and on releasing the button, the speaker of my laptop should output the recorded voice or a speaker attached to the arduino should output.

**Note: I don't want to use any shield to do so. Simply Arduino**

Comment: Which Arduino do you intend to use? Most of them don't have enough built-in storage for any significant amount of audio.

Comment: You will not be able to do this without adding support components such as a pre-amp and storage device, at which point your requirement not to use a shield become a desire to do things the hard way.  Realistically, a basic ATmega-based Arduino is a poor choice for this application.  Many other boards have more appropriate hardware, though perhaps not as user friendly a development environment (something like an STM32F4 Discovery for example has everything you need on board except the speaker).  One of the ARM-based boards from arduino.cc might work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Microphone input is easy (ADC). Speaker output is easy (PWM). Both have many, many examples strewn across the Internet.

What happens in between is *not*, and will require external components. You will need at the very least somewhere to store the samples between record and playback. Investigate SPI SRAM large enough to store all the required samples at your chosen sample rate (8 kS/s should be high enough for human speech).

Comment: I was looking to combine these two concepts http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-SOS-signal-with-8ohms-speaker-LED-blinki/?ALLSTEPS
http://www.instructables.com/id/Connect-the-arduino-and-make-the-speaker-play/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: Neither of those is what you want.